# awk script to print first instance of string

Tags: awk, sed, pipe

I have 2 .dat files:

```
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P /home/james/YCSB/workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://192.168.0.8:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb -p    recordcount=100 -load
new database url = 192.168.0.8:27017/ycsb
mongo connection created with 192.168.0.8:27017/ycsb
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 828.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 120.77294685990339
[INSERT], Operations, 100
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 4279.99
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 588
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 262990
```

And

```
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.JdbcDBClient -s -P /home/james/YCSB/workloads/workloada -p db.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.8:3306/ycsb -p db.user=root -p db.passwd=root -p recordcount=2001 -load
Adding shard node URL: jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.8:3306/ycsb
Using 1 shards
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 3359.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 595.7130098243525
[INSERT], Operations, 2001
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 1259.888055972014
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 401
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 34779
```

I am writing a script that can be used on both of them and collect values dependent on what file it is being used on:

```
cat 100.dat | head | egrep -w 'Operations|Throughput' | cut -f3 -d' ' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } '
```

returns: `100 120.77294685990339`

I require a 3rd column that will contain either `mongodb` or `mysql`. So I need an awk or sed pipe that will search for either string and insert it in a 3rd column.

required output would look like this: `100 120.77294685990339 mysql`

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear - what is the desired output from these files?

Comment: a 3rd column containing either "mongodb" or "mysql". So 100 120.77294685990339 mysql. For example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should do the whole thing in one invocation of awk. The key thing to do is to change your field separator:

```
awk -F'[,=]|://' '/^Command/{db=$2}/Operations/{o=$3}/Throughput/{t=$3}END{print o,t,db}' file
```

The field separator is set to either `,`, `=` or `://`. The parts of the file you are interested in are saved to variables and printed once the file has been processed.

Rather than using the `END` block, you can print when `/Operations/` is matched:

```
awk -F'[,=]|://' '/^Command/{db=$2}/Operations/{print $3,t,db}/Throughput/{t=$3}' file
```

Of course, this assumes that three lines will be found in the order specified in your two examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. awk -F'[,=]|://' '/Command/{db=$2}/Operations/{o=$3}/Throughput/{t=$3}END{print db o t}' works great. I removed the commas at the end as they created extra spaces.

Comment: @JamesF yes, the commas result in the output field separator (a space by default) being inserted between each field. You could adjust your input field separator so that it also contained a space if you wanted but in this case it's probably simpler to just remove the commas.